# Deriving an expression for price elasticity of demand

Tags: calculus

Is this right? I differentiated $P$ to find $\dfrac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dQ}$ then put $ \dfrac{1}{\mathrm dP/\mathrm dQ} $ to find $\dfrac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dP}$ and multiplied $\dfrac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dP}$ by $\dfrac{P}{Q}$ to get the PED expression in terms of $Q$.

The demand is given by the equation:

$$P = 920Q^{-0.4}e^{-0.00005Q}.$$

My answer:
$$ \left(-\frac{x^{1.4}}{368} \cdot (-20000)x^{0.00005}\right) (920Q^{-0.4}e{^{0.00005Q}}).$$

Is my thought process and answer correct?

Comment: probably should define price elasticity of demand for those who do not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demand equation implicitly defines $Q(P)$, so define

$$ F(P,Q) \equiv P - 920Q^{-0.4}e^{-0.00005Q} =0 $$

and use the implicit function theorem to get

$$ \frac{dQ}{dP}= -\frac{F_P(P,Q)}{F_Q(P,Q)}=-\frac{1}{920(0.4+0.00005Q)Q^{-1.4}e^{-0.00005Q}} = -\frac{Q^{1.4}e^{0.00005Q}}{920(0.4+0.00005Q)}.$$

Then, it follows that the price elasticity of demand is

$$ \frac{dQ}{dP}\frac{P}{Q}=-\frac{Q^{1.4}e^{0.00005Q}}{920(0.4+0.00005Q)}\frac{920Q^{-0.4}e^{-0.00005Q}}{Q}= -\frac{1}{0.4+0.00005Q}.$$

Comment: How would you use a given ped value in order to find price charged and quantity at that specific price? I can't see how to do this in my information as it seems it is the reverse of finding the ped? I tried making the PED equation = to -1.89 then solving for Q. But surely you need to find P before finding Q? Regards Rhys

Comment: The elasticity is a function of $Q$, so given a particular value for the elasticity you can solve for the associated $Q$. Then plug this value into the (inverse) demand function to get $P$. By the way, if you are satisfied with an answer you should click the check sign.